# getting message ID of a just send message

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I am writing a thunderbird extension for which I want to perform an action, writing the messageID to a file, when the user sends a message. The user can activate this feature through a new toolbar element.

The problem is that at the moment the "compose-send-message"-event handler triggers the messageID is not defined yet. The best solution I found so far is to write the some identification of the message (recipient, subject,...) to a queue and wait for the newMailListener to trigger for a message with the same identification to be added to the sent mail folder. Is there a better solution for that?
Thanks

Comment: Probably nsIDBChangeListener will be usefull: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDBChangeListener. Although, I didn't tested it.